# How to decode json array in square bracket under curly bracket

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am unable to get array data between square bracket under curly bracket. This is json output:

```
{"data":{"user":[{"transaction":"45455","date":"2013-10-28" }],"msg":"ok"},"error":[]}
```

I have tried this:

```
$obj = json_decode($json_data, true);
$user_data_array = $obj['data']['user'];
```

But I am unable to get data in user array. Waiting for you quick reply and thanks in advance.

Comment: @User016: That's an *answer*, not a comment. :-)

Comment: Checkout http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user_data_array = $obj['data']['user'][0]['transaction'];
```

Comment: His json is **NOT** Valid, so there won't be an array!

Answer (score 1):

I assume the "ok" in the message should be a string? Right now your json is invalid.

```
$json_data = '{"data":{"user":[{"transaction":"45455","date":"2013-10-28"}],"msg":"ok"},"error":[]}';

$obj = json_decode($json_data, true);
$user_data_array = $obj['data']['user'];
```

Comment: Correct, "ok" is the message output. Thanks Ronald.